# SharedIndexInformer (io.kubernetes) not working after few hours randomly

Tags: java, kubernetes, kubernetes-operator

**Background**

I made a PoC of a Java application using the following library:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.kubernetes</groupId>
  <artifactId>client-java-spring-integration</artifactId>
  <version>11.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

The application is creating new k8s Jobs and watch for their events using SharedIndexInformer:

```
BatchV1Api batchV1Api = k8sApiClientService.getK8sBatchV1Api();
return sharedInformerFactory.sharedIndexInformerFor(
    (CallGeneratorParams params) -> {
        return batchV1Api.listJobForAllNamespacesCall(
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                params.resourceVersion,
                null,
                params.timeoutSeconds,
                params.watch,
                null);
    },
    V1Job.class,
    V1JobList.class,
    30000);
```

I starts all informers this way:

```
sharedInformerFactory.startAllRegisteredInformers();
```

And initialize the k8s API this way:

```
apiClient = new ClientBuilder()
        .setCertificateAuthority(Base64.decodeBase64(kubernetesCertificateAuthData))
        .setAuthentication(authentication)
        .setVerifyingSsl(true)
        .setBasePath(kubernetesAPI)
        .build();
OkHttpClient httpClient =
        apiClient.getHttpClient().newBuilder().readTimeout(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
apiClient.setHttpClient(httpClient);
io.kubernetes.client.openapi.Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(apiClient);
```

**What is the problem?**
The informer works great, I succeed to create new Jobs and get informed about completion/error/running events.
But, after a while the inform stopped working and I don't know why.
I see that creation of new Job still works, so this is not a problem of communication.
I thought to upgrade the library to the latest version v16.0.2, but I'm not sure if this will fix the issue.

Can you please assist?

I have tried different resync duration of 30sec to 10min, the resync seems to work, but it seems that specific Jobs are not getting informed, even in the resync events it is missing.

Answer (score 0):

client-java version:13.0.1

I met the same question several times, and recently find it happends when the machine which has apiserver is down.
The java client use okhttp: http1.1、long connection.When the server is down, client don't know. It depends on tcp keep alive to notice,but I don't know why the client don' receive.So I add caltimeout to finish the conenction.

```
  ApiClient apiClient = Config.fromToken(xxx, xxx,false);

        apiClient.setHttpClient(
                apiClient
                        .getHttpClient()
                        .newBuilder()
                        .callTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
                        .build());
```

I make the machine down,and find it works.

This is the func of caltimeout:

```
/**
 * Sets the default timeout for complete calls. A value of 0 means no timeout, otherwise values
 * must be between 1 and {@link Integer#MAX_VALUE} when converted to milliseconds.
 *
 * <p>The call timeout spans the entire call: resolving DNS, connecting, writing the request
 * body, server processing, and reading the response body. If the call requires redirects or
 * retries all must complete within one timeout period.
 *
 * <p>The default value is 0 which imposes no timeout.
 */
@IgnoreJRERequirement
public Builder callTimeout(Duration duration) {
  callTimeout = checkDuration("timeout", duration.toMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  return this;
}
```

set 10 minute just because watch last less than 10 minutes:

```
      Watchable<ApiType> newWatch =
          listerWatcher.watch(
              new CallGeneratorParams(
                  Boolean.TRUE,
                  lastSyncResourceVersion,
                  Long.valueOf(jitteredWatchTimeoutSeconds).intValue()));
```

long jitteredWatchTimeoutSeconds =
Double.valueOf(REFLECTOR_WATCH_CLIENTSIDE_TIMEOUT.getSeconds() * (1 + Math.random()))
.longValue();